# onError event of Telerik for ASP.Net MVC extensions

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

When exactly does the onError event fire for the grid?

I want to know if what I have is sufficient for any errors that occur in my Controller. In my .Layout_cshtml page, I have the below code snippet...

I want to make sure that if an error occurs inside the Catch block, it will display (via the code in the _Layout.cshtml page).

In my controller, inside the Catch, I don't have anything.

What if I have an error with the Model? Will this automatically display as is or do I need to capture the ModelState error (which I know how to do) in the Controller and spit out an alert message here....

In my View, I have the followng:

```
.ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnError("error_handler"))
```

.Layout_cshtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function error_handler(e) {

                if (e.errors) {

                    var message = "Errors:\n";

                    $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {

                        if ('errors' in value) {

                            $.each(value.errors, function () {

                                message += this + "\n";

                            });

                        }

                    });

                    alert(message);

                }

            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnError) it is fired for several reasons. Mainly it is used if there are model state errors during after update. Or if there is error on the server while binding.

It will also get fired if the response returned from the server is not in the correct format.